# What are these coils on transmission lines?

Tags: identification, transmission-line, power-engineering

What are these coils?

[image: What are these coils]

This was asked by doetoe in this [physics.stackexchange Question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/210704/why-the-coil-on-high-tension-wires#comment451218_210704)

> Where I saw them (maybe six or eight pairs) they came in pairs, always on the same two lines, and they were at approximately regular intervals.
>
> It is from Spain, Barcelona area

Comment: I have always presumed that things like this were to stop oscillation in the wind, but I will be interested to know what they are really for.

Comment: I have never seen this particular kind, but I would bet they are dampers, have a google image search for "power line dampers" and you will see a lot of different constructions, some of which are similar, and some of which are nothing like it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its a bird diverter, for make them see the power line and avoid them.

Comment: Thanks. It looks more like [Bird Flight Diverter](http://www.ecvv.com/product/4056002.html) than [spiral vibration damper](http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/ADSS-spiral-vibration-damper_567003625.html).

Comment: To clarify - I asked my senior electrical engineer about how these work. Apparently, birds think that the coiled-up shape is a snake, which might eat them - i.e. it works like a scarecrow. Apparently it **doesn't** work on birds that normally **eat** snakes, such as kookaburras and eagles, which will sit on top of the thing and try to eat it.